# Arithmetic on two CGPoints with + or - operators

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, math, cgpoint

In Objective-C I'm starting to work with `CGPoints` and when I need to add two of them the way I'm doing it is this:

```
CGPoint p1 = CGPointMake(3, 3);
CGPoint p2 = CGPointMake(8, 8);
CGPoint p3 = CGPointMake(p2.x-p1.x, p2.y-p1.y);
```

I would like to be able to just do:

```
CGPoint p3 = p2 - p1;
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, at least in Xcode for iOS I get the error "Invalid operands to binary expression ('CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') and 'CGPoint')"

Comment: Yeah. Not possible in C. You might be able to wrangle something in C++ with operator overloading, but in general, no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And here's the "something" that @ipmcc suggested: C++ operator overloading. **Warning: do not do this at home.**

```
CGPoint operator+(const CGPoint &p1, const CGPoint &p2)
{
    CGPoint sum = { p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y };
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You can overload operators on `struct`s?! I've really got to work on my C++.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Well, `struct`s are really the same as `class`es, except that they have their member visibility set to `public` by default.

Comment: That's quite something.

Comment: @JoshCaswell This is one of the reasons why I don't like C++: you can **never** know what simple operations and expressions do (even in simple cases like this) without digging through all the declarations and implementations...

Comment: It comes down to discipline, I suppose. I could mess with your head by clobbering `-[NSArray addObject:]` with a category in ObjC, too.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yeah, *partly.* Method swizzling is used much less often in Objective-C **in production code** than operator overloading in C++. It's also less straightforward.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I guess it's not possible in Objective-C. Question is about Objective-C, right? Why is this marked correct?

Comment: @Jonny This works in Objective-C++. Just give your source files a .mm extension.

Comment: Here's the reason operator overloading is awesome:

In C#:

`currentVelocity = (currentVelocity - num * vector3) * d;`

In ObjC:

`*velocity= ccpMult(ccpSub(*velocity, ccpMult(vector3, num)), d);`

Answer (score 3):

You can't use arithmetic operators on `struct`s, unfortunately. The best you can do is a function:

```
CGPoint NDCGPointMinusPoint(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2)
{
    return (CGPoint){p1.x-p2.x, p1.y-p2.y};
}
```